# What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using'?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using-declaration

I know that in C++11 we can now use `using` to write type alias, like `typedef`s:

```
typedef int MyInt;
```

Is, from what I understand, equivalent to:

```
using MyInt = int;
```

And that new syntax emerged from the effort to have a way to express "template typedef":

```
template< class T > using MyType = AnotherType< T, MyAllocatorType >;
```

But, with the first two non-template examples, are there any other subtle differences in the standard? For example, `typedef`s do aliasing in a "weak" way. That is it does not create a new type but only a new name (conversions are implicit between those names).

Is it the same with `using` or does it generate a new type? Are there any differences?

Comment: I personally prefer the new syntax because it is much more similar to regular variable assignment, improving readability. For example, do you prefer `typedef void (&MyFunc)(int,int);` or `using MyFunc = void(int,int);` ?

Comment: I fully agree, I only use the new syntax now. That's why I was asking, to be sure there is really no difference.

Comment: @MatthieuM. those two are different btw. It should be `typedef void MyFunc(int,int);` (which actually doesn't look as bad), or `using MyFunc = void(&)(int,int);`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah thanks, I did not know of the first form and thought it was equal to the `using` form I presented. Indeed the first is not too bad (except for having the name in the middle).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes why do you need **(&)** in  `using MyFunc = void(&)(int,int);` ? does it mean `MyFunc` is a reference to a function? what if you omit the **&**?

Comment: Yes, it's a function reference. It's equivalent to `typedef void (&MyFunc)(int,int);`. If you omit the `&` it's equivalent to `typedef void MyFunc(int,int);`

Comment: In [this episode of CppCast](http://cppcast.com/2015/08/edouard-alligand/) Edouard Alligand claims that `using` results in faster link times (don't remember which compiler he was talking about, though), because apparently the compiler generates shorter symbol names. I don't know if this holds up to scrutiny, though.

Comment: Irrespective of the actual answer:  thank you @Klaim for helping me with the template syntax  -  your naming convention is much clearer than the standard code snippets.

Comment: @WillC Note that both notations are standard, but the first one is "legacy".

Comment: I don't think this warrants a separate question, but what does this look like using `using`?
  `struct Private;
  typedef int(Private::*Zero);` (Found in Qt's QFlags.h.)
I simply cannot make sense of the syntax.

Comment: The [core guidlines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rt-using) suggest `using` over `typedef` for defining aliases

Comment: I changed the accepted answer because someone finally found a tiny difference that can be noticed in some ... "advanced" kind of codebases. Thanks @dfri

Comment: `using` is C++ only, `typedef` can be used in C also.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

### Typedef declarations can, whereas (until C++23) alias declarations cannot, be used as initialization statements

> But, with the first two non-template examples, are
> there any other subtle differences in the standard?

- Differences **in semantics**: none.
- Differences **in allowed contexts**<sup>(+)</sup>:

  - C++20 and earlier: some.
  - C++23 and onwards: none<sup>(++)</sup>.

<sup>(+) Not including the examples of *alias templates*, which has already been mentioned in the original post.</sup>

<sup>(++) [P2360R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2360r0.html) (*Extend init-statement to allow alias-declaration*) [has been approved by CWG](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1034) and as of C++23, this inconsistency between typedef declarations and alias declarations will have been removed.</sup>

#### Same semantics

As governed by [[dcl.typedef]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#2) [extract, **emphasis** mine]

> **[dcl.typedef]/2** A
> [*typedef-name*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#nt:typedef-name)
> can also be introduced by an
> [*alias-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:alias-declaration).
> The *identifier* following the `using` keyword becomes a
> *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the *identifier* appertains to that *typedef-name*. **Such a
> *typedef-name* has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.** [...]

a *typedef-name* introduced by an *alias-declaration* has **the same semantics** as if it were introduced by the `typedef` declaration.

#### Subtle difference in allowed contexts

However, this does **not** imply that the two variations have the same restrictions with regard to **the contexts** in which they may be used. And indeed, albeit a corner case, a [*typedef declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#1) is an [*init-statement*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.stmt) and may thus be used in contexts which allow initialization statements

```
// C++11 (C++03) (init. statement in for loop iteration statements).
for (typedef int Foo; Foo{} != 0;)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
{
}

// C++17 (if and switch initialization statements).
if (typedef int Foo; true)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
{
    (void)Foo{};
}

switch (typedef int Foo; 0)
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
{
    case 0: (void)Foo{};
}

// C++20 (range-based for loop initialization statements).
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
for (typedef int Foo; Foo f : v)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
{
    (void)f;
}

for (typedef struct { int x; int y;} P; auto [x, y] : {P{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}})
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
{
    (void)x;
    (void)y;
}
```

whereas before C++23 (this answer may have prompted [P2360R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2360r0.html) which addressed this niche subtlety in C++23) an [*alias-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:alias-declaration) is **not** an *init-statement*, and thus **may not** be used in contexts which allows initialization statements

```
// C++ 11.
for (using Foo = int; Foo{} != 0;) {}
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression

// C++17 (initialization expressions in switch and if statements).
if (using Foo = int; true) { (void)Foo{}; }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression

switch (using Foo = int; 0) { case 0: (void)Foo{}; }
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression

// C++20 (range-based for loop initialization statements).
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
for (using Foo = int; Foo f : v) { (void)f; }
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression
```

Comment: Wow, my intuition was right in the end! There is a difference! Thanks for finding that difference, it's the kind of very very narrow detail that can make a difference in the kind of code I work with (unfortunately XD).

Comment: I've never seen this usage of typedef anywhere. Since when is this allowed and what are possible usage patterns of this? Looks kind of horrible to me tbh...

Comment: `auto [x, y] : {P{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 5}}) { (void)x; (void)y; }` What is this called? Where can I find more on this?  (Btw, it has one missing open parenthesis.)

Comment: Is there `template - typedef`? similar to `template - using`?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Construction of an std::initializer_list from {…}; skipping the `P` part starting with the second argument as it’s assumed; structured binding declaration to assign to x and y.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB the opening parenthesis is on the previous line.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB, as pointed out by @4xy's answer, there is no such thing as a template `typedef`, and there is no such thing planned in the near future (C++23).

Comment: @RichardVodden Indeed. Note that this is mentioned already in the answer (see (+)).

Comment: A c++23 the alias declaration with using in an init statement will be allowed as well (you can try on coliru) So then this difference between typedef and using is also gone.

Comment: @DanRechtsaf Yes, this is mentioned in the answer, see (+). I'll can update the title to make it more clear as others have missed this also. It's likely that this answer prompted P2360R0.

Answer (score 702):

They are equivalent, from the standard (emphasis mine) (7.1.3.2):

> A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The
>   identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
>   optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains
>   to that typedef-name. **It has the same semantics as if it were
>   introduced by the typedef specifier.** In particular, it
>   does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.

Comment: From the answer, `using` keyword seems to be a superset of `typedef`. Then, will `typdef` be deprecated in future ?

Comment: @iammilind I don't think so as it is part of C and certainly will not be removed from it. Also, C++11 and future versions will still keep maximum compatibility with our current code...

Comment: Deprecation doesn't _necessarily_ indicate intent to remove--It merely stands as a very strong recommendation to prefer another means.

Comment: @iammilind `typedef` is unlikely to become extinct. For one, the current [Standard Library design guidelines](http://isocpp.org/std/library-design-guidelines) have a clause "where C++ 2003 syntax can be used, they are preferred over C++ 2011 features". Of course, in user code no such restrictions apply.

Comment: But then I wonder why they didn't just allow typedef to be templated. I remember having read somewhere that they introduced the `using` syntax precisely because the `typedef` semantics didn't work well with templates. Which somehow contradicts the fact that `using` is defined to have exactly the same semantics.

Comment: @celtschk: The reason is talked about in the proposal `n1489`. A template alias is **not** an alias for a type, but an alias for a group of templates. To make a distinction between `typedef` the felt a need for new syntax. Also, keep in mind the OP's question is about the difference between non-template versions.

Comment: What about with template-templates? A typedef for one of the template template parameters doesn't appear to be suitable as the typedef isn't correct unless it itself has template parameters specified. Can the type alias be used here, or is it equivalent to a typedef in this case (and can't be used)? Or is the solution to this a template type alias? That's a difference between a type alias and a typedef then, yes?

Comment: So why this redundancy whas introduced ? 2 syntaxes for the same purpose. And I don't see `typdef` being deprecated ever.

Comment: I have had an experience which `using` was faster than `typedef`.

Comment: In theory, they're the same except that with `using`, you can use templates, but you cannot with `typedef`.

Answer (score 422):

They are largely the same, except that:

> The alias declaration is compatible with templates, whereas the C
>   style typedef is not.

Comment: Particularly fond of the simplicity of the answer and pointing out the origin of typeset.

Comment: @g24l you mean typedef... _probably_

Comment: What is the difference between C and C++ in `typedef` if I may ask?

Comment: This is not answering the question though. I already know that difference and pointed at in the original post. I was asking only about the case where you don't use templates, is there differences.

Comment: removing the word 'largely ' would make this clearer

Comment: @McSinyx, there is no difference.

Answer (score 234):

The **using** syntax has an advantage when used within templates. If you need the type abstraction, but also need to keep template parameter to be possible to be specified in future. You should write something like this.

```
template <typename T> struct whatever {};

template <typename T> struct rebind
{
  typedef whatever<T> type; // to make it possible to substitue the whatever in future.
};

rebind<int>::type variable;

template <typename U> struct bar { typename rebind<U>::type _var_member; }
```

But **using** syntax simplifies this use case.

```
template <typename T> using my_type = whatever<T>;

my_type<int> variable;
template <typename U> struct baz { my_type<U> _var_member; }
```

Comment: I already pointed this in the question though. My question is about if you don't use template is there any difference with typedef. As, for example, when you use 'Foo foo{init_value};' instead of 'Foo foo(init_value)' both are supposed to do the same thing but don't foillow exactly the same rules. So I was wondering if there was a similar hidden difference with using/typedef.

Answer (score 29):

They are essentially the same but `using` provides `alias templates` which is quite useful. One good example I could find is as follows:

```
namespace std {
 template<typename T> using add_const_t = typename add_const<T>::type;
}
```

So, we can use `std::add_const_t<T>` instead of `typename std::add_const<T>::type`

Comment: As far as I know, it's undefined behavior to add anything inside the std namespace

Comment: @someonewithpc I was not adding anything, it already exists, I was just showing an example of typename usage. Please check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv

Comment: Is the `typename` keyword in the RHS optional? I.e., `template<typename T> using add_const_t = add_const<T>::type;` seems equivalent to the above code I guess. If anyone has advice on this, any comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 16):

I know the original poster has a great answer, but for anyone stumbling on this thread like I have there's an important note from [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1489.pdf) that I think adds something of value to the discussion here, particularly to concerns in the comments about if the `typedef` keyword is going to be marked as deprecated in the future, or removed for being redundant/old:

> It has been suggested to (re)use the keyword typedef ... to introduce template aliases:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   typedef std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> > Vec;
> ```
>
> That notation has the advantage of using a keyword already known to introduce a type alias. However, it also displays several disavantages [sic] among which the confusion of using a keyword known to introduce an alias for a type-name in a context where the alias does not designate a type, but a template; `Vec` is **not** an alias for a type, and should not be taken for a typedef-name. The name `Vec` is a name for the family `std::vector<•, MyAllocator<•> >` – where the bullet is a placeholder for a type-name.Consequently we do not propose the “typedef” syntax.On the other hand the sentence
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   using Vec = std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> >;
> ```
>
> can be read/interpreted as: *from now on, I’ll be using `Vec<T>` as a synonym for `std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> >`*. With that reading, the new syntax for aliasing seems reasonably logical.

To me, this implies continued support for the `typedef` keyword in C++ because it can still make code more *readable and understandable*.

Updating the `using` keyword was specifically for templates, and (as was pointed out in the accepted answer) when you are working with non-templates `using` and `typedef` are mechanically identical, so the choice is totally up to the programmer on the grounds of readability and communication of intent.

Answer (score 16):

Both keywords are equivalent, but there are a few caveats. One is that declaring a function pointer with `using T = int (*)(int, int);` is clearer than with `typedef int (*T)(int, int);`. Second is that template alias form is not possible with `typedef`. Third is that exposing C API would require `typedef` in public headers.

Answer (score 9):

As of now, C++23 will get `typedef` and `using` closer together: [P2360](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2360r0.html) proposes that `using` constitute an *init-statement* such as the ones listed in [@dfrib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573247/)'s answer as `error: expected expression`.

However, even with P2360, a `typedef` cannot be a template.

(*Edit* [2022-09-14]: This contained incorrect information.)

In total, `using` is strictly more powerful than `typedef`, and IMO more readable, too.