# C++ 'typedef' vs. 'using ... = ...'

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using-directives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between typedef and using in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11)

The following code compiles and runs. My question is what is the difference between the "typedef" and "using" method for renaming the template specialization?

```
template<typename T>
struct myTempl{
    T val;
};

int main (int, char const *[])
{
    using templ_i = myTempl<int>;
    templ_i i;
    i.val=4;

    typedef myTempl<float> templ_f;
    templ_f f;
    f.val=5.3;

    return 0;
}
```

### Edit:

If there is no difference, which one would you prefer? / Why was the using ... = ... version introduced?

Comment: A `using` that is not a template is not really the use-case this was introduced for.

Comment: -1. exact dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11

Comment: @Andrew You're right, I just wan't able to find that.

Comment: @Simon: first link in google: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%2B%2B+11+typedef+vs+using&oq=c%2B%2B+11+typedef+vs+using&gs_l=hp.3...1866.13293.0.13428.35.27.6.2.2.0.299.3079.13j10j3.26.0...0.0.Bzu6yzNHsAU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7e21084bce2178cc&biw=1276&bih=706

Comment: Have you noticed that C++11 is moving to a left-to-right declaration style everywhere? The use of `using` to write type alias is more consistent with new C++11 style. The phrase is from Herb Sutter http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**They are the same.**

To quote the C++11 standard (or the draft to be specific):

> A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The identifier following the ***using*** keyword
>   becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the identifier appertains to that
>   *typedef-name*. It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the **typedef** specifier. In particular, it
>   does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the *type-id*.

I think the *"the same semantics as the typedef specifier"* say it all.