# Import nested classes into namespace - C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Say I have a class like this:

```
class A {
public:
    class B {
        // ...
    };
    static void f();
    // ...
};
```

I can refer to `B` as `A::B` and to `f()` as `A::f()`, but can I import `B` and `f()` into the global/current namespace? I tried

```
using A::B;
```

but that gave me a compilation error.

Comment: Was the compilation error, "error: ‘A’ is not a namespace"?

Comment: You cannot do that for `A::f()`.

Comment: @iammilind but you can achieve that behavior with a workaround.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use namespace aliases for the class:

```
using B = A::B;
```

However you can't do that with the member function, not even with static member functions.

**Edit:** According to [this SO answer (What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10748056/440558) this *should* be valid, and actually creates a type alias in the same way that `typedef` does. However, it's C++11 only.

---

There is a workaround for static member functions in C++11, by declaring a variable pointing to the static function:

```
struct Foo
{
    static void bar()
        { }
};

auto bar = Foo::bar;
```

**Edit:** Of course, having a global variable pointing to a static member function is possible in the older C++ standard as well, but it's more messy than using the `auto` keyword of C++11. In the example above it would be:

```
void (*bar)() = Foo::bar;
```

Comment: ``using B = A::B;`` this will not work. Another point is that function pointers cannot be inlined.

Comment: @SergeyK. Works fine for me, with GCC 4.7.1. But you're right about the inlining.

Comment: 1.cpp:9:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'B'
 using B = A::B; ``(gcc.EXE (GCC) 4.8.0)``

Comment: @SergeyK. Actually, the `using` keyword syntax is legal in C++11. When compiling with GCC did you use the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` flags?

Answer (score 33):

Here are two workarounds for your problem:

**1)** Class B:

```
typedef A::B B;
```

**2)** Function f():

```
inline void f()
{
    A::f();
}
```

But think twice before using them.

**Edit:** In C++11 you can do `auto f = A::f;` but this actually creates a pointer to a function and functions pointers cannot be inlined.

Comment: For the `typedef`or `using` solutions, any idea to make it work even with private nested class?

Answer (score 11):

You can `typedef`

```
typedef A::B B;
```

Comment: You could also create `f()` in the global namespace that calls `A::f()`.