# How to make a vim map to after some treatment pass foward to the natural treatment

Tags: vim

I want to map a Shift + Insert, as I usually paste code for studing (or even take some of stackoverflow's questions to prepare an answer). But as mapped for .cpp and .h the pasted code appears messed up.

Example:

```
1  class A {
2 }
3 public:
4     class B {
5     }
6             // ...
7             //     };
8             //         static void f();
9             //             // ...
10             //             };
11             //             )
```

Original code from question [Import nested classes into namespace - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647376/import-nested-classes-into-namespace-c):

```
class A {
public:
    class B {
        // ...
    };
    static void f();
    // ...
};
```

To avoid this is necessary to run: `:set paste`.

So, the question is, how to map a Shift + Insert, just like `imap <S-Insert> <Esc>:set paste<CR>i` and very here pass foward the Shift + Insert to its natural behavior, that is pasting and then turn back and set `:set paste!` back?

Obs.:
{ is mapped to break line and put and ending }, along with that kind of maps the pasted text will be messed up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help 'paste'`:

> Since mapping doesn't work while 'paste' is active, you need to use
>   the 'pastetoggle' option to toggle the 'paste' option with some key.

So the solution is to e.g.

```
:set pastetoggle=<F12>
```

and to use the following sequence when pasting: `<F12>i`(paste)`<Esc><F12>`

Answer (score 1):

Vim's own special registers `*` and `+` allow bypass the shaky pasting through terminal. `"*p` pastes from X selection register and `"+p` pastes from clipboard. In Windows these are both linked to same IIRC.

Comment: It only works in gvim, doesn't in vim using konsole or gnome-terminal, thanks.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel, actually it works in plain vim as well. Just need to enable some compile flags if your distro doesn't provide a binary for that.