# glfwOpenWindowHint not declared in this scope GLFW3 & GLEW

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-3, glfw

Following some OpenGL tutorials for OpenGL 3+, Right out of the gate, I've run into some discrepancies, here is the code I managed to get, but right out of the gate, I'm getting this massive slew of errors, none of which say it can't find the included headers, but merely that the headers don't define the core functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main(){

// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //I don't want the
                                                                   //old OpenGL

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 01" );

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

do{
    // Draw nothing

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );
```

The problem being the fact that MinGW doesn't like this very much and has produced a ton of
"undeclared" errors, all of which are required for an OpenGL window to exist.  I've never worked with any graphics library other than a little bit of SDL2, so you may need to walk me through this... Which would be very appreciated.

```
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:23:20: error: 'GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:23:40: error: 'glfwOpenWindowHint' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:24:20: error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR' was not declared in this
scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:25:20: error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR' was not declared in this
scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:29:48: error: 'GLFW_WINDOW' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:29:60: error: 'glfwOpenWindow' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:43:35: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'GLFWwindow*' for
argument '1' to 'void glfwSetWindowTitle(GLFWwindow*, const char*)'
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:46:30: error: 'glfwEnable' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:52:21: error: too few arguments to function 'void
glfwSwapBuffers(GLFWwindow*)'
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:55:20: error: 'GLFW_KEY_ESC' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:56:21: error: 'GLFW_OPENED' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:56:33: error: 'glfwGetWindowParam' was not declared in this scope
SigmaGLPP\main.cpp:56:36: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

Comment: Have you managed to load basic shaders?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use `GLFW3` headers but the code you wrote is for `GLFW2`.

In `GLFW3` the function `glfwOpenWindowHint()` is renamed to `glfwWindowHint()`

Check out this page for upgrade instructions: http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html There are a lot of things that changed since `GLFW2`.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: Check out the upgrade page link in my answer. There are a lot of things you should upgrade.

Comment: The link helped a lot, I didn't realize that so much changed from GLFW2 to 3. Also, that response was a lot faster than I was expecting, haha. Hope to see you around!

Comment: @MathosNatrim: You are welcome! Maybe you can help here a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11647849/1065190 :)