# Getting `undefined reference to 'glfwOpenWindowHint' ` error when trying to run OpenGL SuperBible example code on Linux

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, archlinux

I'm trying to sun OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition example code for the first time on my Manjaro (arch) system.
I followed the HOWTOBUILD.txt, installed mesa and glfw (glfw-wayland, not sure if there is a difference) via pacman. Tried to run the first time unsuccessfuly, then changed an error in the CMakeList.txt as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474361/9197461
it got rid of the `undefined reference to 'glfwInit'` error, but all other undefined errors stayed. Can anyone help me compile this without errors?

code example:
https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code

full error when I try to run `make`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o: in function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x8b): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xa1): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xb0): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xbf): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xd5): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o:wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xf5): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o: in function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x133): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18b): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1e9): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x25b): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x267): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x280): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x289): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x29a): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bc): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/build.make:105: bin/wrapmodes] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:296: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the source code and tried the steps you've done and not surpringsingly, received the same error message.

And it seems that the source code uses GLFW2 instead of GLFW3.

`glfwOpenWindowHint` is renamed to `glfwWindowHint` in GLFW3

See: [glfwOpenWindowHint not declared in this scope GLFW3 & GLEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363093/glfwopenwindowhint-not-declared-in-this-scope-glfw3-glew)

You could try installing GLFW2 and run it again. Since GLFW2 is available in Ubuntu Xenial, remember to configure `sources.list` accordingly.

## For OpenGL SuperBible 6th

**EDIT**:
I could not manage to install `libglfw2` from Ubuntu Xenial repository. And manually installed `dpkg` from official website.

1. download `.deb` file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libglfw-dev
2. go to the folder `.deb` is installed in and run `sudo dpkg -i [name of libglfw2].deb`
3. Run `find . -name "libglfw*"` in `/usr/lib` to find the path to the library. (there can be multiple `libglfw.so` as you already downloaded `GLFW3` so be careful)
4. Create a symbolic link for the dynamic library just installed by running the following command:

   `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/[path to file]/[filename] /usr/lib/[path to file]/libglfw2.so`
5. Edit `sb6code/CMakeFiles/tunnel.dir/link.txt` as follows

   `-lglfw` to `-lglfw2`
6. Run `make`

## For OpenGL SuperBible 7th

If you have already installed `libglfw3` but could not manage to run `cmake ..`, this could be because your `libglfw3.so` is stored as `libglfw.so`.

In that case, you can create a symbolic link to it:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/[path to file]/[libglfw name].so /usr/lib/[path to file]/libglfw3.so`

Save and run `cmake ..` again inside `build`.

If it fails because of linker, make sure you have all the dependencies:

```
libglfw3-dev libx11-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxi-dev libxxf86vm-dev libxcursor-dev
```

Comment: Can you explain how to configure sources.list? or can you give me a link to a documentation?

Comment: more accurate one: https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs

Comment: @SnakesCantWearBoots I edited the answer to help you. Ask me if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @SnakesCantWearBoots I just realised you are using Arch Linux. Then, this might not be a solution.

Comment: I know this is different now, but I tried to launch the 7th version code which is in http://www.openglsuperbible.com/example-code/ under `Download the OpenGL SuperBible Example Source Code (master repository at GitHub)` and I'm getting `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3` error. I've installed the latest glfw-wayland from AUR, don't understand why it's still not working

Comment: Can you go to the `/usr/lib/` and run `find . -name "libglfw*"` or `whereis libglfw`? Because linker and the corresponding `.lib` file should have the exact name.

Comment: @SnakesCantWearBoots I added instructions for SuperBible 7th I used to successfully build the source code.