# How to send input to child console application

Tags: c++, console, message, createprocess

I am spawning a child console process (zip.exe) from an MFC application

```
static TCHAR  s_atchZipTool[] = _T("\\tools\\zip.exe");
sArgZip.Format(_T("%s%s -e -r %s *.*"), GetAppPath(), s_atchZipTool, sFilePathName);
if( !CreateProcess(NULL, (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) sArgZip, NULL, NULL, 
                    FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, sFilesPath, &si, &pi) ) 
{
    return ::GetLastError();
}
else
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
}
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

So when I do not need to set password for zipped file everything is fine, but how can I send multiple messages as console input to this process? Parameter -e forces me to put 2 more strings "Enter password", "Verify password".

Comment: It's a lot of work, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't know what you're up to, but from the smell of it, I'd think it a job for Python, not C++/MFC.

Comment: Use 7zip instead. It allows to set encryption password through the command line.

Comment: @Ari0nhh Thats not an answer, anyway it solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import nested classes into namespace - C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647376/import-nested-classes-into-namespace-c)