# How to simplify notation with many template arguments and use it in another template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use Google hash map which declaration is

```
template <class Key, class T, class HashFcn, class EqualKey, class Alloc>
class dense_hash_map { ... };
```

and put this template class as one of arguments in another template classes like

```
template<template<class Key, class T, class HashFcn, class EqualKey, class Alloc > class GoogleHashTable, class SomeOtherClass>
class MyClass     {    };
```

I want to simplify previos notation to be something like this

```
template<GoogleTemplate class GoogleHashTable, class SomeOtherClass>
```

but how to define `GoogleTemplate` as

```
template<class Key, class T, class HashFcn, class EqualKey, class Alloc >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11,

```
 template <template <typename...> class GoogleHashTable, class SomeOtherClass>
```

otherwise

```
 template <
      template <typename, typename, typename, typename> class GoogleHashTable,
      class SomeOtherClass
 >
```

Now, it you want extra-simplification, e.g. in C++11

```
 template <template <typename...> class F>
 struct temp
 {
      template <typename... A>
      using map = F <A...>;
 };

 template <class G, class SomeOtherClass>
 class MyClass
 {
      template <typename... A>
      using GoogleHashTable = G::template map <A...>;
 };
```

This further simplifies the declaration of `MyClass`, but needs an extra template alias within its definition if you want to use template `GoogleHashTable` as usual, without the `::template map` stuff.

Also, to use `MyClass`, you now have to write

```
MyClass <temp <GoogleHashTable>, SomeOtherClass>
```

instead of

```
MyClass <GoogleHashTable, SomeOtherClass>
```

except of course if you

```
typedef temp <GoogleHashTable> /*some name*/;
```

**EDIT**

On C++03 or earlier:

```
 template <template <typename, typename, typename, typename> class F>
 struct temp4
 {
      template <typename A1, typename A2, typename A3, typename A4>
      struct map { typedef F <A1, A2, A3, A4> type; };
 };
```

similarly, `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3` etc. Then in your class:

```
 template <class G, class SomeOtherClass>
 class MyClass
 {
      // now GoogleHashTable <A1, A2, A3, A4>
      // is expressed as typename G::template map <A1, A2, A3, A4>::type
 };
```

This is much less convenient but if you have `A1, A2, A3, A4` arguments fixed at some point within `MyClass`, then

```
 typedef typename G::template map <A1, A2, A3, A4>::type Table;
```

will save you lots of typing.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot figure it what 3 dots should represent. Can you give me some tip?

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia entry for [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates#C.2B.2B11).

Comment: Ok, I use Visual Studio 2008, which probably does not support C++11 standard. Can I simply define alias (some string) which will be replaced in compile time? Is there some other solution without C++11?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include this. It's not that convenient, but can still work.

Comment: It looks like it will work and save lots of typing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can do a lot with `using` directive. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) discussion.