# How to declare a function return a pointer to function return pointer to int[3]

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying the following declarations:

```
int (*(*((*foo)(const void *))()))[3];
```

and

```
int (*(*(*foo)(const void *)()))[3];
```

But the compiler gives me an error:

```
error: 'foo' declared as function returning a function
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/742cb7607eecb222)

Is it possible at all in c++?

Comment: Are you asking for C or C++; dual tagged questions get short shrift.  Since you mention C++, I've removed the C tag (even though there's a decent chance in this case that the answer is much the same).  The languages are different; in many respects, quite different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought `c++` as `c` also use cdecl, doesn't it?

Comment: You can't have an array as the return type of a function What do you mean by "return int[3]"?

Comment: You cannot return arrays from functions; you can return pointers to arrays, though.

Comment: As in, `int (*(*foo())(const void *))[3]`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler C and C++ are not that different.  Remember that C++ was originally implemented by Stroustrup as a preprocessor for C, which is why they share a great many things: scope rules, declaration syntax and semantics, all of C's base types, etc. etc. etc.  Sure, C++ adds a great deal more, but for 99.9% of cases, a valid C program is also a valid C++ program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that derived declarations work is that you replace the identifier in the declaration with the new thing you are deriving. For example in the first step here, to get from "pointer to int[3]" to "function returning pointer to int[3]", we take the declaration for "pointer to int[3]", and change the identifier to be a function declarator.

A pointer to int[3]:  **int (*name)[3];**

A function returning that: int (* **name()** )[3];

A pointer to that: int (* **(*name)** () )[3] - parentheses required otherwise the `*` binds to the other `*` instead of to `name`

A function returning that: int (* (* **name()** ) () )[3]

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```c++
int (*(*f())())[10];
```

or even cleaner (kinda):

```c++
using array_type = int (*)[10];
using return_type = array_type (*)();

return_type f();
```

Comment: Why you use using instead of typedef?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv - it is c++11 syntax - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11)

Comment: @SteveLorimer Why does `typedef int(*)[10] array_type;` throw a compile-time error? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97b34742374d9008

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax for function pointer typedefs. The correct syntax is `typedef int (*array_type)[10];`

Answer (score 5):

Use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/).

```
cdecl> declare f as function returning pointer to function returning pointer to array 3 of int
int (*(*f())())[3]
```

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare+f+as+function+returning+pointer+to+function+returning+pointer+to+array+3+of+int