# typedef and using in c++11

Tags: templates, c++11, typedef

```
#include <iostream>

struct cls {
    using type = double;          //case 1
    // typedef double type;         //case 2
};

template<typename T>
void foo(typename T::type) {
    std::cout<<"T::type\n";
}

int main() {
    foo<cls>(22.2);
}
```

I believe `using` and be used instead of `typedef`.
In the above code I'm getting error for `case 1` but not for `case 2`.

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'type'
```

Could someone please explain why??

Comment: it does work: http://ideone.com/x4HHHc

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/4gD45z What compiler version and flags do you use?

Comment: I used GCC4.9, but didn't  mentioned -std==c++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler either [doesn't support C++11 type aliases](http://ideone.com/tz9CJH), has limited support for them (MSVC used to incorrectly parse template types when not used) or hasn't the C++11 option active, make sure you're using a C++11 compatible (and enabled) one, i.e. upgrade your compiler.

```
struct cls {
    using type = double;         // Doesn't work on pre-C++11
    // typedef double type;      // Works on pre-C++11
};
```

I'm also recommending reading the [difference between using and typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) in C++11