# Referring to nested classes in a compact way

Tags: c++

I have my classes/structs declared the following way:

```
namespace NS {
class A {
    public:
    struct B {
        int x;
        int y;
    }
}
}

int main() {
    NS::A::B objB;
}
```

I am wondering if there is any way I can refer to B in a more compact way. I tried using "using" but that only seems to work for namespaces.

Comment: if you have a C++11 compiler a type alias (`using`) should have worked though a `typedef` should suit your needs pre-C++11(and post-C++11 for that matter). How exactly did you try to use `using` and what error did you get?

Comment: I think he thought of something like `using namespace NS::A;` (maybe with a somewhat different syntax) as if `A` was a nested namespace. At least, that's something i would have liked to do, but i can understand why it's not possible. But he can indeed use `using b_t = NS::A::B;` instead of `typedef NS::A::B b_t;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a typedef: `typedef NS::A::B MyB`.

Then your main becomes:

```
int main() {
    typedef NS::A::B MyB
    MyB objB;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using "using" but that only seems to work for namespaces.

Using works just fine:

```
namespace NS {
    class A {
        public:
        struct B {
            int x;
            int y;
        };
    };
}

using MyB = NS::A::B;

int main() {
    NS::A::B objB;
    MyB objB2;
}
```

There is [some discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) about this solution as opposed to the typedef approach.  The conclusion is that they are equivalent.

Comment: there is the possibility the compiler used by the OP is pre-C++11 and does not support type aliases

Comment: (you can also move either `using` or `typedef` inside the `main`'s body, just to emphasize that this solution isn't any different from Phil's which uses `typedef`)

Comment: @YoungJohn Then it's not a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

typedef ? Tested in Code Blocks:

```
namespace NS {
class A {
    public:
    struct B {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
};
}
typedef NS::A::B NSAB;


int main() {

    //NS::A::B objB;
    NSAB objc;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want an alias-declaration, not a using-declaration or using-directive. You need to provide a name:

```
using AB = NS::A::B;
```

This is particularly more readable in some cases, and can be used in templates unlike `typedef`.

For example:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    struct Bar {};
};

template<class T>
using Bar = typename Foo<T>::Bar;
```