# Function determining its return type in C++

Tags: c++, return

Trying to write a function that determines its own return type according to some preprocessor directives. But i am not sure if this is possible in C++.

```
type ConvertStrIfNecessary(){
    std::str mystr="abcdefghif";
    #ifdef MYCONDITION
    return mystr.c_str();
    #else
    return mystr;
    #endif

}
```

Comment: Your `#ifdef MYCONDITION` yields undefined behaviour, if you use the `char*` afterwards.

Comment: But then you have to use MYCONDITION preprocessor stuff everywhere, like for instance "type" should also be specified using the preprocessor conditional and have either char * or std::string. Also when they call your function, they will also have to write preprocessor conditional stuff. The correct way of providing different return types is through overloads of that function.

Comment: yes , indeed thats my question . is there anyway to avoid that ? This function is just to show what i want to achieve . a function that returns different types according to some conditionals ( does not have to be preprocessor , it can also be simple if - else statement, too)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your compiler and whether it supports [N3638](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html) ([g++ since 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html)):

```
/* 
vvvv "auto" is enough */
auto ConvertStrIfNecessary(){
    std::string mystr="abcdefghif";
    #ifdef MYCONDITION
    return mystr.c_str();
    #else
    return mystr;
    #endif
}
```

You need to enable C++14 with `-std=c++14` in GCC. Keep in mind that C++14 support is still experimental. Note that this only works if all `return`s in your function return values of the **same** type. Since there's only one `return` after preprocessing it's fine in this case.

Your users could then use `auto` again:

```
auto theValue = ConvertStrIfNecessary();
```

That being said, your code yields undefined behaviour if you return `mystr.c_str()`, since the pointer returned by `c_str()` is invalidated when `mystr` goes out of scope.

Even worse, `const char*` and `std::string` have different semantics, and the code will most likely not compile later since some client used `theValue` as `char*`, where someone else used it as `std::string`.

If you really want different types, you could instead provide a common interface type:

```
#ifdef MYCONDITION
using stringlike_t = const char *;
#else
using stringlike_t = std::string;
#endif
```

That gives you control on the "safe" methods a user can use.

Comment: Why use `using` rather than `typedef`?

Comment: @ilent2: [They're the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11). And I just kinda messed up the typedef, since I accidentally wrote `typedef stringlike_t = const char*`. Was easier to replace `typedef` with `using` than to swap both arguments and delete the `=` :D.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything with preprocessor commands you could define your own string type

```
#ifdef MYCONDITION
#define STRING_TYPE const char*
#else
#define STRING_TYPE std::string
#end
```

Then your function would be

```
STRING_TYPE ConvertStrIfNecessary(){
    std::string mystr="abcdefghif";
    #ifdef MYCONDITION
    return mystr.c_str();
    #else
    return mystr;
    #endif
}
```

But, again, be careful with returning `.c_str()`.  However, apart from the use of `std::string`, this is very much the C way of doing things, prefer a solution like `auto` if your using C++ (see Zeta's solution).

Comment: Why `#define STRING_TYPE`? Why not `typedef .. STRING_TYPE` or `using STRING_TYEP =`, which gives better error messages?

Comment: @Zeta Because it is all C-style preprocessors and will work in both a C and C++ header (as long as `MYCONDITION` is synonymous for `__cplusplus`).

Comment: The `using ...`, sure. But the `typedef` is safe in a C header.

Comment: @ilent2 Why should we care about interoperability with C when it's not needed? We don't do the same treatment for Java or Python either. And if `std::string` is a valid option, that rules out C anywya.

Comment: @Angew No reason, I just thought it an interesting corollary and perhaps somewhat relevant or worth consideration if the OPs question was related to working with importing some C library that works with `char*`.