# Is there a way to embed a class in a new namespace with the same name?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, typedef, facade

We're attempting to hide a class behind a new namespace, however we'd like to keep the original name.

```
namespace first {
    class Logger { ... };
}

namespace second {
    using Logger = first::Logger;
}
```

> error: definition of type 'Logger' conflicts with type alias of the
>   same name
>       class Logger;

Comment: `namespace second = first;`? :o)

Comment: We are looking to just take specific elements into the new namespace.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Does the posted code not compile?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6126b94eb2c73d5).

Comment: Should probably just delete this question in light of the fact that the answer involves is a minor issue unrelated to anything in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can:

```
namespace first {
  class Logger {  };
}

namespace second {
  typedef first::Logger Logger;
}
```

[typedef is apparently equivalent to using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) (in C++11), just more wieldy.

Comment: Probably because I advised to use "typedef" instead of providing a way to do it with "using".

Answer (score 1):

Right-o, this was due to a forward declaration of type class Logger within our own codebase.

```
namespace first {
    class Logger { ... };
}

namespace second {
    using Logger = first::Logger;

    ... some time later ...
    class Logger;
}
```