# C++ - error: 'BO3' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, struct

```
class BO2Offsets
{
    public:
        struct Prestige
        {
            u32 Offset { 0x000000 };
            char One { 0x01 },
                Two { 0x02 },
                Three { 0x03 },
                Four { 0x04 },
                Five { 0x05 },
                Six { 0x06 },
                Seven { 0x07 },
                Eight { 0x08 },
                Nine { 0x09 },
                Ten { 0x0A },
                MasterPrestige { 0x0B },
                CheatedPrestige { 0x0C };
        };
};
BO2Offsets BO2;
```

main.c

```
BO2 *BO3;
```

I'm creating a new element as BO2 but it's returned me an error:

```
error: 'BO3' was not declared in this scope
```

How can I resolve this ? 
EDIT:
When I declare BO3 like that:

```
BO2Offsets *BO3;
```

I use BO3 like this:

```
BO3->Prestige->Offset
```

And I'm getting an error: error: invalid use of 'struct BO2Offsets::Prestige'|

Comment: Complete minimal example now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BO2 isn't type, is only variable name, and compiler want type.

use

```
BO2Offsets * B03;
```

EDIT:
in the second place 
use

```
BO3->Prestige.anyName.Offset;
```

EDIT2; OK folks, if everyone edit his contents, I edit too:
struct is improperly introduced, field cannot bee accessed. Now such concept compiles OK on modern GCC. BTW such introduction of `Prestige` isn't too useful, is similar like 'anonymous class' (to some degree). I allays declare struct / class at higher level. In this fragment can bee omitted.
But give name for field (my `anyName`) is important to access his internal fields.

```
class BO2Offsets
    {
        public:
            struct Prestige
            {
                u32 Offset { 0x000000 };
                char One { 0x01 },
                    Two { 0x02 },
                    Three { 0x03 },
                    Four { 0x04 },
                    Five { 0x05 },
                    Six { 0x06 },
                    Seven { 0x07 },
                    Eight { 0x08 },
                    Nine { 0x09 },
                    Ten { 0x0A },
                    MasterPrestige { 0x0B },
                    CheatedPrestige { 0x0C };
            } anyName; // here !!!
    };
```

Comment: You can't use `Prestige` like that. It's not a data member. And quit downvoting everyone in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `typedef` there. What you have right now is a variable declaration.

Change `BO2Offsets BO2;` to `typedef BO2Offsets BO2;`

---

As to your second question, you can't use `Prestige` like that because it is not data member. If you need to access the inner type, you need `BO2Offsets::Prestige::Offset`

Comment: Dont use typedef, is is obsolete in C++

Comment: `typedef` is obsolete in C++? What? I know you don't need the C-style `typedef` for structs, but saying it is obsolete is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: introducing variables in C++ was simplified, and typedef lost his sense from old C. Deprecated in in-formal sense.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you want to use `BO2` as an alias for `BO2Offsets`, you need a typedef.

Comment: I prefer the new style: `using BO2 = BO2Offsets;`, but they are [equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10748056/4944425).

Answer (score -1):

BO3 is nothing in your case.

You need to cast BO3 at first.

```
BO2Offsets BO3;
```

or

```
BO2Offsets *BO3;
```