# Proper way to define type (typedef vs #define)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Which of these methods is more secure for defining variable types? I know that we all frown when we see #defines, but it seems to work just as well as typedef here:

Is there an advantage one way or the other, and if so what might it be?

Method One:

```
    #include <iostream>

    #define byte unsigned char

    int main() {
        byte testByte = 'A';
        std::cout << testByte << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Method Two:

```
     #include <iostream>

     int main() {
        typedef unsigned char byte;

        byte testByte = 'A';
        std::cout << testByte << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What does "more secure" mean?

Comment: Your method 1 is horrible practice.

Comment: Prefer actual language features over preprocessor features whenever possible. In other words, avoid macros.

Comment: #define is dangerous as it does search and replace like operations to your code before compiling. Wrong things could be substituted.

Answer (score 13):

You should always use the 2nd one (i.e. [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) or [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)).

Try to not use macros in c++ as far as possible, and most cases could be avoided. They're just text replacement before compiling, and more "dangerous". e.g.

```
#define byte_pointer unsigned char*
byte_pointer p, q; // only p is a pointer
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer

Comment: I should also mention that that you should define a separate header with these `using` or `typedef` declarations, it will not only scope everything to a single file, but allow you too change values in one and only one place.

Answer (score 6):

Only one of your examples actually is a way to define a type, so there's no contest between them.

---

```
#define byte unsigned char
```

This just makes all utterances of `byte` in your code get replaced with `unsigned char` before compilation begins. It does not define a type.

The declaration `int byte;` will become `int unsigned char;`, which is nonsense.

---

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

This defines a type. The type will be subject to syntax rules, scoping rules and all of that lovely stuff.

The declaration `int byte;` will still be the declaration `int byte;`, because `byte` here is found in the space for a variable name.

---

```
using byte = unsigned char;
```

This is the "modern" way to define a type alias, which has much clearer syntax than a `typedef` statement (especially for more complex types).

It was introduced because otherwise the new syntax for *template* type aliases would have been next to impossible to make sane.

Answer (score 1):

Using #define is not safe (see other answer)
Using typedef is the usual way to define types aliases.

There's also the new "using" syntax

```
using MyByte = unsigned char;
```

see this answer to a related question (typedef vs. using) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10748056/446303

Answer (score 0):

Go with the `typedef`. There are many reasons, but the first one that comes to mind is that the `typedef` applies to the scope where it is declared, but the `#define` ignores scope and applies to the remainder of whatever source module it is defined in. For that reason alone, the `typedef` is "safer".