# std::conditional with unknown type

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

I'm currently writing a library which makes use of C++20's `std::span`. Compiler library support for `std::span` is at this point rather scarce. Therefore, I have a marco which allows to use a 3rd-party implementation instead (in my case [`tcb::span`](https://github.com/tcbrindle/span)). The macro looks like this:

```cpp
#ifdef SPAN_BUILTIN
#   include <span>
#   define SPAN std::span
#else
#   include "3rdparty/span.hpp"
#   define SPAN tcb::span
#endif
```

Usage through the library looks like this:

```cpp
void my_func(const SPAN<int>& s);
```

This is not pretty at all. I was looking for a better solution and I came across `std::conditional` which I have already used in the past. A naive attempt would looks like this:

```cpp
constexpr const bool span_builtin = // ...

template <class T>
using span_type = typename std::conditional<span_builtin, std::span<T>, tcb::span<T>>::type;
```

Which would result in usage like this:

```cpp
void my_func(const span_type& s);
```

The problem lies in the fact that `std::span` is an unknown type at compile time when `std::span` is not available which makes compilation fail.

Is there a nicer solution to this?

Comment: Why don't you just declare an alias called `span` in the `std` namespace, write code that simply references `std::span`, and simply drop the alias when you update your compiler?

Comment: Change `#   define SPAN std::span` to `template <typename T> using span =  std::span<T>;`.  Also make the corrisponding change to the third party lib line.

Comment: Why not just use `tcb::span` everywhere? That will save a great deal of debugging.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That would be Undefined Behavior, and break compilers where the `std::span` implementation exists but is not yet standard-conforming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

Let's answer it step-by-step

```cpp
constexpr const bool span_builtin = // ...
```

Does something like this exist?

Would this work?

Probably not

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594334/1691072

We could use this but the issue with this is that below C++20, Span would not be defined

[Also we cannot officially add our own span Forward Declaration to std namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/1691072)

So what's the solution?

The solution would end up being very similar to yours

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

#if __cplusplus > 201703L // Do something else for MSVC if you cannot use `/Zc:__cplusplus`
#include <span>
template<typename T, std::size_t N = std::dynamic_extent>
using span = std::span<T, N>;
#else
template<typename T>
using span = tcb::span<T>;
#endif

int main ()
{
#if __cplusplus > 201703L
   static_assert(std::is_same_v< span<int>, std::span<int>>);
#else
   static_assert(std::is_same_v< span<int>, tcb::span<int>>);
#endif
}
```

See also [Proper way to define type (typedef vs #define)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518029/proper-way-to-define-type-typedef-vs-define)