# What is "template<class T> using owner = T;"?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias, ms-gsl

Below is excerpted from `gsl.h` of Microsoft's `gsl` library (https://github.com/microsoft/gsl):

```
namespace gsl
{
    //
    // GSL.owner: ownership pointers 
    //
    using std::unique_ptr;
    using std::shared_ptr;

    template<class T>
    using owner = T;
    ...
};
```

I cannot understand what the following alias template means:

```
template<class T>
using owner = T;
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that for every `T`, `owner<T>` is an alias for `T`.

Comment: Isn't it that owner is an alias of T. Not owner<T>

Comment: @West, No, `owner` is a template. `T` is a type.

Comment: Yup I was so wrong on this. For everyone like me this compiles. static_assert(is_same<int,owner<int>>(),"hello");

Answer (score 2):

It can be used as annotation to show which pointers are 'owner' ie:

[Example of non owning raw pointer](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-ptr)

```
template<typename T>
class X2 {
    // ...
public:
    owner<T*> p;  // OK: p is owning
    T* q;         // OK: q is not owning
};
```