# owner<T*> p syntax in cpp core guidelines

Tags: c++, c++14, cpp-core-guidelines

In cpp core guidelines: [Example of non owning raw pointer](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning)
I do not understand the following code:

```
 template<typename T>
class X2 {
    // ...
public:
    owner<T*> p;  // OK: p is owning
    T* q;         // OK: q is not owning
};
```

what is this syntax `owner<T*> p` ?

Comment: `p` is an instance of the class `owner` which is a template and accept the parameter `T*`? is that what you are asking?

Comment: is it linked to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449366/what-is-templateclass-t-using-owner-t)?

Comment: yes! now I really understand where it comes from! this is declared in the microsoft library as an empty template

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a note about the semantics of `owner` further down the page:

> **Note** `owner<T*>` has no default semantics beyond `T*`. It can be used without changing any code using it and without affecting ABIs. It is simply a indicator to programmers and analysis tools. For example, if an `owner<T*>` is a member of a class, that class better have a destructor that `delete`s it.

It's basically the almost same as the proposed [`std::observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr). The difference is that `owner` stores a pointer and "owns" it, although it doesn't do any RAII like `std::unique_ptr`. It should be used when you want to be more explicit that a raw pointer is a owning pointer.

Note that the "syntax" here is just a variable of a template class, it's not a keyword or something.

Comment: so 'owner' is  not a cpp keyword it is just a template which is defined somewhere else?

Comment: @user3880722 Exactly :)

Comment: @Galik It's also basically the same in that it does nothing.

Comment: @Galik I see what you mean. The semantics are different, but they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As Rakete1111 mentioned, `owner<T*>` is the same as T*. So we can have `owner` as a type alias for T.

```cpp
template<class T>
using owner = T;
```

Now we can have a convention for our code that pointers are defined by `owner` when the class containing them is responsible for deleting them.

A simple example that owner acts as a raw pointer:

```cpp
owner<int*> p = new int;
*p = 1;
std::cout<<*p; // 1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.