# C++: template class inheritance with variable-type parameters using parameter packs

Tags: c++11, templates, inheritance

(I had no idea how to name this question and I couldn't find anything similar. Sorry if this is duplicate)

If I want to inherit from some base template class, I can do this that way:

```
template<typename A=int, typename B=char> class C {};
template<typename... Args> class D : public C<Args...> {}; //it works!
```

This way I can change in project passed parameters to template class C and I don't have to change every usage of class D. Great. But what if I have template class using not only types as parameters but also values? For example:

```
template<int dim=3, typename float_t=double> class GeometricObject{};
template<typename... Args> class Point : public GeometricObject<Args...>{}; //it doesnt work
```

Of course I could define last template with integer type on the beginning. But this is not a way, if I would have 100 different classes all inheriting from GeometricObject and then I would change default `dim` value to 2, I would have to change every single class definition.

I also hope that there is the way without using any `#define`, `#else` and similar preprocessor commands. I know that templates are in fact also preprocessor commands, but... well, let's be modern here ;)

Comment: are your value parameters separated from the type parameters, i.e. do the value parameters always come first like this `template<int x=3, int y=2, typename X = int,  typename Y=double>` ?

Comment: It could be. If I don't know a general answer then specific answer is good too :)

Comment: Can't you just pass the specialized template directly and access the parameter pack with appropriate typedefs?

Comment: Example plz, I'm not very good template-bender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not mix type and non-type parameters in a template parameter pack. But it seems that your `Point` and other derived classes don't need to access the parameter pack arguments separately. In such cases it's easier, as well as more semantically correct, to pass the base class:

```
template<int dim=3, typename float_t=double> class GeometricObject{};
template<class GeometricObject=GeometricObject<>> class Point : public GeometricObject{};
```

Instantiating a `Point` could then look like:

```
Point<> a{}; // the same as Point<GeometricObject<>> a{};
Point<GeometricObject<4>> b{};
Point<GeometricObject<2, float>> c{};
```

Of course the `GeometricObject<...>` could be typedef'd to something shorter. Also, it can be made to look like a namespace instead of providing parameters to each geometric object separately:

```
template<int dim = 3, typename float_t = double>
struct GeometricObjects {
  using Base = GeometricObject<dim, float_t>;
  using Point = ::Point<Base>;
  // ...
};

using TwoDim = GeometricObjects<2>;
TwoDim::Point a{};
```

Comment: What wizardry is this o.O I thought that `using` statements was the domain of C#. Thanks for response!

Comment: `using TwoDim = GeometricObjects<2>` is the same as `typedef GeometricObjects<2> TwoDim`, just more "modern" :-)

Comment: Which part looks like wizardry? I'll be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Just `using` statements in a way as you use types of variables. It's almost like finding python-like smart shortcuts in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. I adapted the subsequent text to it. Here's a link for the `using` syntax here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have multiple template classes and you want your `Point` object to be able to inherit from them all.

Instead of doing:

```
template <typename ... Args>
class Point : public GeometricObject<Args...>{};
```

I would instead do:

```
template <typename T>
class Point : public T {};
```

Now we just have to define proper traits to access the types template parameters in case they are needed. These types should be factored into a `std::tuple` (for instance).

The burden to fill this trait is on the `GeometricObject` class. For example, with your definition we would have:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_parameters;

template <int N, typename Float>
struct type_parameters<GeometricObject<N, Float> {
    typedef std::tuple<Float> types;
};
```

The main scenario: a method of `Point` needs the type template parameters of `GeometricObject` (to forward them to a method of `GeometricObject`). To achieve this, you will have to pass in a `tuple` that will be unfold to call the inner method. To do so I make use of features added in the STL for C++14. You could still rewrite them yourself but I spared me the hassle for this question...

```
template <typename T>
class Point : public T {
    template <typename Method, typename ... Args, std::size_t ... Is>
    auto call_unfold(Method method, std::tuple<Args...> const& tuple, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>) {
        return (this->*method)(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
    }
    template <typename Method, typename Tuple>
    auto call_unfold(Method method, Tuple const& tuple) {
        return call_unfold(method, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
    }
public:
    typedef typename type_parameters<T>::types types;
    void some_method(types const& args) {
        return call_unfold(&T::some_method, args);
    }
};
```

This example is quite meaningless but the same technique could be useful with constructors of `Point` that need to call a base class constructor.

A live demo showing how it works is available on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dde2c935a2c719f4)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. Looks like I don't have an option, I need to make more complex code if I want to mess with templates. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out how I should include variable-type template parameters into tuples. Basically I need to 'encapsulate' them into new parameter. This example works perfectly well AND solves my problem:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int n = 2> struct Dim {
    const int dim = n;
};

template<typename T> class SillyBaseClass {
public:
    typedef typename T dim;
};

template<typename... Args> class SillyDerivedClass : public SillyBaseClass<Args...>{
public:
    typedef typename SillyBaseClass::dim dim;
    SillyDerivedClass() {
        static_assert(std::is_same<dim,Dim<2>>::value,
            "Number of dimensions must be equal to 2");
    }
};

int main() {

    SillyDerivedClass<Dim<2>> Class2d;    //this works
    SillyDerivedClass<Dim<3>> Class3d;    //this returns expected error

}
```