# How do I create a map with iterator values?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to define a class with a map of `K` -> `pair` of `V` and iterator of a `list` of `K`. This is to implement LRU cache. I got this working with `decltype`:

```
template <typename K, typename V> class LRUCache {
  std::list<K> q;
  typedef decltype(q.begin()) Iterator;

  typedef std::pair<V, Iterator> Node;

  int max_size;
  std::map<const K, Node> m;
}
```

However, I am not satisfied with using `decltype` and it all seems brittle when I try to use it. What would be the canonical way of doing this?

Comment: `std::list<K>::iterator`

Comment: @Holt this doesn't work error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::__cxx11::list<K>::iterator’ because ‘std::__cxx11::list<K>’ is a dependent scope
   typedef std::list<K>::iterator Iterator;

Comment: `typename std::list<K>::iterator`

Comment: `typedef typename std::list<K>::iterator Iterator;`, this is written in the error message actually.

Comment: When I use `typename std::list<K>::iterator Iterator;` then it fails on declaration of `typedef std::pair<V, Iterator> Node;`, if I change them all to `typename`, I get different errors.

Why do I need to use `typename` instead of `typedef`?

Comment: @Zereges, is it safe to keep list iterators in a map?

Comment: @Qwertiy If all rules corresponding to such iterators are satisfied (i.e. itearator validity), why not?

Comment: @ThamP You need `typedef typename std::list<K> iterator Iterator;` (both keywords).

Comment: Having a `const` key in `std::map` is pointless as it's already immutable.

Comment: Tip: you could use `using` instead of `typedef`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11

Comment: @Zereges, but is it in case of usage from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite do not like old fashioned way of using `typedef`, since it seems to use reverse syntax for declaring stuff. You are also using `int i = 5` and not `int 5 i`. (Not only) for this, new usage of `using` was introduced.

```
using Iterator = decltype(a.begin());
```

If you do not like `decltype`, you can use `std::list<K>::iterator`, but because `K` is template parameter, `std::list<K>` is *dependent name* and needs to be prefixed with `typename`.

```
using Iterator = typename std::list<K>::iterator;
```

Or with old fashioned `typedef`

```
typedef typename std::list<K>::iterator Iterator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the iterator is

```
std::list<K>::iterator
```

If you want to use it, you have to use a `typename` in front of it, or alias it first with a

```
using iterator = typename std::list<K>::iterator;
```

However, using `decltype` there seems to be a perfectly valid use of it, if you can be sure everyone calling this code has c++11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers of others - the `std::list<K>::iterator` is a *dependent type* and C++ requires us to use `typename` in front of it.

The reason for this is that the compiler doesn't know whether `::iterator` is a type, so it needs a hint with `typename`.

Another way of dealing with the original issue is to use `using` template, similar to the way some of `<type_traits>` are defined in C++14. We can define:

```
template <typename T> using ListIterator = typename std::list<T>::iterator;
```

Now, we can simply use `ListIterator<K>` in the LRUCache code:

```
template <typename K, typename V> class LRUCache {
  using Node = std::pair<V, ListIterator<K>>;
  std::list<K> q;      
  std::map<const K, Node> m;
  int max_size;
}
```