# confirm understanding of typedef and #define

Tags: c++, typedef

There are lots of tutorials and quesitons addressing this. But I want to confirm my understanding in one specific case. The two below should not make a difference to the compiler i.e either one is correct. Right?

```
typedef _GridLayoutInputRepeater<_num-1,Figure,_types...> _base;
```

and

```
#define _base _GridLayoutInputRepeater<_num-1,Figure,_types...>
```

Similarly , the below should not make the difference?

```
#define INT_32 uint32_t
```

and

```
typedef uint32_t INT_32;
```

EDIT : Follow up thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719583/follow-up-on-understanding-of-defines-and-typedef)

Comment: You should really be using `using`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 : means? can you please give an example?

Comment: Don't use "underscore uppercase" [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier ]. Personally I don't like to see any leading underscores as it makes user code look like system headers, but I'm seeing it more and more as C++ gets pythonized.

Comment: @infoclogged Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) about it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 : thanks, using is indeed much readable. Didnt know that its an alternative to typedefs

Answer (score 4):

Currently without showing use-cases the 2 situations are both "equal" but what you should note is that `#define` is a whole different beast than `typedef`.

`typedef` introduces an alias for another type, this alias will be seen by the compiler and thus will follow compiler rules, scoping etc.

A `#define` is a preprocessor macro, the preprocessor will run before the actual compiler and will literally do a textual replacement, it does not care about scoping or any syntax rules, it's quite "dumb".

Usually, `typedefs` are the way to go as they are so much less error-prone. In which case you could use `using =` as well but that's personal preference since they're both the same:

```
using _base = _GridLayoutInputRepeater<_num-1,Figure,_types...>;
```

Comment: In which uses cases would the above fail i.e one ( typedef )  works but the other ( #define ) does not?

Comment: @Rakete1111 very interesting, but why does #define fail here #define bar int   bool bar = true; // fail . and typedef int bar bool bar = true; is successful !

Comment: @infoclogged Because for the typedef, the compiler sees that `bar` already has a type attached. For the #define, the compiler doesn't see it because it's already been replaced by the preprocessor, it only sees `bool int = true;`.

Comment: @infoclogged `foo` is declared to be a type and is not considered in `bool foo=true`. But `bar` is #defined to be `int`, i.e. the compiler sees `bool int=true` which makes no sense.

Comment: @Walter what do you mean by not considered in bool foo=true? Is the replacement of foo in bool foo = true ignored by the compiler because it already sees a type bool?

Comment: @infoclogged I don't know the exact rules, but it seems that `typedef` only introduces an alias, and not a type, and so the alias type is allowed to be shadowed by another name.

Comment: added  a new thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719583/follow-up-on-understanding-of-defines-and-typedef

Comment: One important disadvantage of using the brutal text substitution of a `#define` for types is that you are missing the "regularization" that `typedef` does to types made of more than one token. Once you `typedef` a complex declaration such as `unsigned int`, `int (*)[4]`, `void (*)(int, double)` and similar, you can use functional cast notation, add qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`), create pointers and references, ... with the usual syntax; the `#define` doesn't act as a "syntax firewall", and thus such operations are either impossible or require complex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `#define` rather than `typedef` or `using` is that [as has been pointed out] `#define` is a macro, and macros are evaluated and expanded by the preprocessor, so the compiler knows nothing about the data type you're trying to create because the `#define` directive is simply substituted with whatever comes after it.

The reason for using macros in languages such as C and C++ is to allow for things that aren't specifically to do with source code logic but are to do with source code structure.

The `#include` directive, for instance, quite literally includes the entire content of a file in place of the derective.

So, if `myfile.h` contains:

```
void func_1(int t);
void func_2(int t);
```

then

```
#inlude "myfile.h"
```

would expand the content of `myfile.h`, replacing the `#include` preprocessor directive with

```
void func_1(int t);
void func_2(int t);
```

The compiler then comes along and compiles the expanded file with class definitions, and other expanded macros!

It's why the macro

```
#pragma once
```

or

```
#ifndef  __MYFILE_INCLUDE__
#define __MYFILE_INCLUDE__
```

is used at the start of header files to prevent multiple definitions occurring.

When you use an expression like `#define INT64 unsigned int` the preprocessor does exactly the same thing. It evaluates the expression, then replaces all occurrences of `INT64` with `unsigned int`.

When you use a typedef, on the other hand, the compiler makes the type substitution, which means the compiler can warn about incorrect use of your newly created type.

`#define` would simply warn you of an incorrect use of `unsigned int` which if you have a lot of type substitution can become confusing!