# Difference between #define and typedef when using its name to define a variable

Tags: c++, typedef

This is a follow up to this question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718664/confirm-understanding-of-typedef-and-define).

```
typedef int foo;
#define bar int

int main() {
    bool foo = true; // ok
    bool bar = true; // fail
}
```

the `typedef` works, but I am curious to know how can the typedef here work?

How does the final compiled code looks like with respect to `foo`? According to few answers, `typedef` is an alias and alias is allowed to be shadowed. Hence the code works.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Type names in general are allowed to be used to define a variable with the same name What I mean is this:

```
typedef int foo; // can't be in the same scope as the below definitions
struct foo { foo(int) {} }; // same thing as above

int foo = 0; // ok
foo bar = 1; // ok
foo foo = 2; // ok
```

But with `#define foo int`, there is no `foo` type/alias:

```
#define foo int
int foo = 0; // fail
foo bar = 1; // ok
foo foo = 2; // fail
```

The above is actually (after the preprocessor runs):

```
int int = 0; // fail
int bar = 1; // ok
int int = 2; // fail
```

If you had another definition, `bool foo = true;`, then it will become `bool int = true;`, which also fails to compile.

But there is an exception: `int` is a reserved keyword, which means you can't define any variables with that name. But if it were another type like `struct bar{};`, then that part will compile.

Answer (score 0):

The first works because you are supplying a type and not using the typedef.  The second fails because the macro is substituting int for bar.

```
typedef int foo;
#define bar int

int main() {
    bool foo = true; // ok   
           // You have created a new bool variable named foo.
           // There is no relation to the typedef foo.
    bool bar = true; // fail
           //  Essentially you are saying
           //           bool int = true;
           //  which doesn't compile - you can't have a variable named
           //  int because it's a reserved keyword.
}
```

Comment: I think the question really is *Why is there no relation to the `typedef` foo?* I.e. what does the `typedef` really doing?

Comment: @Walter typedef cannot create new language keywords, so it's not a problem to reuse those words.

Answer (score 0):

I variable may have the same name as a type: you have an unused type foo and a variable foo with type bool.