# What are the differences between "typedef", "using", "namespace" and "using namespace" in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, typedef, using

I find it difficult to get the exact meaning of these terms in C++. It seems like there is a lot of overlap between one another (at least typedef and namespace). Can you please enlighten me why were these concepts invented in C++; and in what scenarios should we use each one of these ?

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) discussion is particularly confusing. It says 'typedef' and 'using' are the same. It makes me wonder, why do we have two different terms if they are almost the same ?

Due to poor understanding of these terms I coded the following and got the error shown below:

**Files.hpp**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

class Files {

public:

//@Brief: We create some short forms for long type names
typedef boost::filesystem FS; //! Short form for boost filesystem
// Short form for file name pairs (for example, <200.jpg, 200>)
typedef std::pair<FS::path, int> file_entry;
// Short form for vector of tuples
typedef std::vector<file_entry> vec;
// Short form for iterator of type, boost::filesystem::directory_iterator
typedef FS::directory_iterator dirIter;
};
```

The following is the *make* error that I receive:

```
...../include/Files.hpp:10:20: error: ‘filesystem’ in namespace ‘boost’ does not name a type
 typedef boost::filesystem FS; //! Short form for boost filesystem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::filesystem` is a namespace, not a type.  So you can do this:

```
namespace FS = boost::filesystem;
```

Comment: Pardon me if I am wrong. But this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11) is the discussion I referred to. It says that typedefs and namespace are the same. Now I am confused.

Comment: They are not equivalent. You can use `using` in place of a `typedef` but not the other way around.

Comment: Typedefs and namespaces are certainly not the same.  That question you linked has nothing to do with namespaces (it doesn't even contain the word "namespace").

Answer (score 2):

Since `boost::filesystem` isn't a type but a `namespace`. Use a namespace alias at file scope:

```
namespace FS = boost::filesystem;
```