# templated using VS public inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, using

I believe `using` keyword was added in order to allow template typdefs. However I came across to one compilation error, here is simplified code:

```
template <bool EnableFirst, class T1, class T2>
struct OneOfTwo {};
template <class T1, class T2>
struct OneOfTwo<true, T1, T2>
{
    using type = T1;
};
template <class T1, class T2>
struct OneOfTwo<false, T1, T2>
{
    using type = T2;
};

struct A
{
    static constexpr int X = 1;
};

struct B
{
    static constexpr int X = 12;
};

struct C {};
struct D {};

template <class T1, class T2>
using ClassX = OneOfTwo<T1::X == T2::X, C, D>::type;            //C4346: 'T2::X': dependent name is not a type;  C2061: syntax error: identifier 'type'

template <class T1, class T2>
struct ClassY : public OneOfTwo<T1::X == T2::X, C, D>::type {}; //OK
```

And I use these classes like this:

```
ClassY<A, B> y;
ClassX<A, B> x;
```

I believe `ClassX` and `ClassY` should be exactly same thing, however `ClassX` causes compilation error. So my question is: which part of C++ standard did I break?

BTW, I'm using MSVC 2015 toolset with XP support (v140_xp).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `typename` keyword:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
using ClassX = typename OneOfTwo<T1::X == T2::X, C, D>::type;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `using` keyword requires **types** in its definition:

```
using ABC = SomeClass;
```

But *`ABC`* is **not a type, it is a *type alias (a.k.a `typename`)***...

So, this line fails:

```
using ClassX = OneOfTwo<T1::X == T2::X, C, D>::type;
```

> C4346: 'T2::X': dependent name is not a type;  C2061: syntax error: identifier 'type'

A more accurate representation of this error would be:

> Error: `typename` is not `class`...

*typename* is a specifier for type-aliases which can be *anything*, from `int`s to `void*`s to anything... But a class has its own identity... it's a **class**...

So, in order to fix your error you have to specify `typename` before a type alias...

```
// Adding the 'typename' keyword is also needed for nested classes, according to YSC
using ClassX = typename OneOfTwo<T1::X == T2::X, C, D>::type;
```

Read: [*Type aliases*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

---

**Edit:** Doing something like this will also yield the same thing:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct OneOfTwo<false, T1, T2>
{
    typedef T2 type;
}
```

In `typedef` though, you **[cannot make an alias of a type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11), just like you do with `using`, so `using` has an advantage**...

**Note:** As suggested: adding 'typename' is considered redundant since C++20...

Comment: `So, in order to fix your error you have to specify typename before a type alias...`

Note, that it's no longer necessary starting from C++20. Now, `typename` is automatically assumed/inferred in the context there the is no ambiguity (like using declaration since it can only contain type). See [P0634R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) (currently only implemented in GCC 9).

Comment: @DanM. Note that Microsoft's compiler still doesn't support *C++20* and looks like the OP is using the Microsoft compiler anyways... It might be good if they soon implemented it...

Comment: true for VS2015, but I'm just noting that in case someone encounters the same error on a newer compiler in the future (since since VS2017 it uses standard switches too and C++20 won't become the default for a long while but might be still available as a switch).

Comment: I'm not a fan of your explanation. `typename` is not needed _because_ `type` is a type-alias; it would equally be needed if it was a nested class. [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06fd6c8cde64a4f5)