# Representing two or more data types with a single reference in CPP

Tags: c++

In my code, for certain variables I always have to write unsigned long long for the declaration of the variables.
Is there a way to represent unsigned long long using a single word, something like "ULL", and then use this syntax to declare other variables. Eg ULL amount;

Comment: `using ULL = unsigned long long;`

Comment: you should consider "using" as a better answer, even if in this case it is exactly the same thing. The "using" approach is to be preferred as it also works with templates (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959200/4759678)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using ULL = unsigned long long;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to declare it like this:

```
typedef unsigned long long ULL;
```