# Using vs typedef in class

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using, using-declaration

I thought the new `using` syntax in C++11 and `typedef` were equivalent (except for templates). But it seems that with `using` it is also not possible to declare a class member.

```
class A {
   //... Public members 
private:
    typedef std::vector<double> vector_double; 
    using vector_int = std::vector<int>;        

    void bar(vector_double& vecDouble); // type can be used
    void foo(vector_int& vecInt); // type can't be used: synatx error
 // ... Possible other private members
}
```

When I try to use the type `vector_int` in one of the member functions of class A I get a compiler error: `syntax error: identifier 'vector_int'`.

Am I doing something wrong here or is defining a member type not possible with `using`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This should work as expected. If it's `gcc` or `clang`, try `-std=c++11`?

Comment: This could be the problem, I use an old Visual Studio compiler which I think only supports some C++11 features. I will check the version.

Comment: There was a discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11

Comment: Although I use Visual Studio 2017 IDE, the _MSC_VER I get with `printf("_MSC_VER : %d \n", _MSC_VER);`is 1600 which is Visual Studio's 2010 compiler version 10.0. I guess this explains the problem. Thanks @lubgr.