# Short Parameter Type in C++

Tags: c++

Let`s say I have a class named Graph. I want to shorten the parameter list by using shorter type names. Is it possible to do that?

```
void Graph::APUtil(int u, vector <bool> visited, vector <bool> disc,  
                   vector <bool> low,  vector <bool> parent, vector <bool> ap)
```

I tried using auto but it does not work:

```
void Graph::APUtil(int u, auto visited, auto disc ...
```

I think since this is a class method lambda also does not work.

Any suggestion? I am asking this to save time in coding challenges.

Comment: have you considered using `typedef`? and or `#define`?

Comment: When you say "save time" do you mean your *own* time writing the code, or saving time for the compiler or execution? Because something like this will increase the compile-time as the compiler need to do more work. And it won't have any effect on run-time.

Comment: Also note that using type-aliases (introduced with either `typedef` or `using`) generally makes the code harder to read and understand, unless you create descriptive names with some semantic meaning which means you probably have just as much to write as before if not more. Using single-letter symbols or names is a bad habit that should never be used in "real life" (and unfortunately bad habits do tend to stick, so even initially limited use will spread).

Comment: @CS_EE as side note, are you sure of passing everything by copy?

Comment: @Moia this was just an example

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean my own time. Since time is limited I aim to limit time spent on typing.

Comment: @CS_EE then use alias

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 ways to do this.

- [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) type alias;
- [`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) specifier;
- [`#define`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) directive.

Macro [`#define`] should be avoided. `typedef` and `using` are [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11), so you may use any of them.

Let's consider syntax of `using` type alias:

```
using identifier attr(optional) = type-id;
```

So, for your code you should write

```
using v = std::vector<bool>;
// . . .
void Graph::APUtil(int u, v visited, v disc,  
               v low, v parent, v ap);
```

Comment: `using` is superior to typedef and should be preferred. The explanation is in the same thread you linke.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`typedef`](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/typedef-statement-in-c/) to define shorten the typenames like.

```
typedef vector<bool> bvec;
```

or if you're using `c++11` standard, the preferred way is [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) as suggested by @Yehor like

```
using bvec = vector<bool>;
```

in the end which ever option you use you can modify your method signature to

```
void Graph::APUtil(int u, bvec visited, bvec disc,  
           bvec low, bvec parent, bvec ap);
```

Comment: `using` is preferred over `typedef`

Comment: @Moia Thanks for the suggestion, `using` is one of the newer constructs, supported by c++11 and up, I prefer `typedef` since op didn't mention which standard he's using for his project.

Comment: keep in mind that "newer" means 9 years ago. At least C++11 should be considered as standard, not C++98. @Minato

Comment: @Moia "newer" is a relativistic term, and  Again OP didn't specify the standard, in which case I prefer to use the older constructs.