# Shorten usage of std::shared_ptr<std::vector<shared_ptr<VariousClassNames>>>

Tags: c++, stl

I was reviewing my code, and I found out that i use often these constructs:

`std::shared_ptr<std::vector<shared_ptr<ClassA>>>`

`auto instance = std::make_shared<std::vector<shared_ptr<ClassB>>>()`
 etc.

Is there a valid opportunity to set a shortcut for the `std::make_shared<std::vector<shared_ptr<$CLASSNAME$>>>` or `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<shared_ptr<$CLASSNAME$>>>` phrase?

something like `using svs<ClassA> = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<shared_ptr<ClassA>>>` **(invalid syntax; does not compile!)**

Is there another opportunity, than using a template?

Greets

Comment: You might use template alias.

Comment: q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11

Comment: Are you really want `std::shared_ptr<std::vector</*..*/>>`?

Comment: To emphasize the point made by @Jarod42, pointers to containers are seldom if ever needed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another opportunity, than using a template?

No; a template is literally what you're asking for.

This is correct:

```
template <typename ClassA>
using svs<ClassA> = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<shared_ptr<ClassA>>>;
```

There is no other way to make it work unless you write lots of different aliases yourself for different cases.

As an aside, that's a *lot* of indirection. Are you sure you need so many layers of `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Well, not quite _literally_ - it's a template _alias_ that should be used here, not a (new) template.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The standard calls them "alias templates" (c.f. function templates, class templates); I think it's reasonable to think of these things as kinds of templates. cppref also says _"An alias template is a template which [..]"_

Comment: Ok, I concede :D

Comment: @MaxLanghof Boom :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to your question "_As an aside, that's a lot of indirection. Are you sure you need so many layers of shared_ptr?_": I need to handle variable numbers of ClassA. I have access them via pointer and using a vector around these ClassA-Instances. Would you consider this a "not clean" code? Is there a better way?  I would be happy about corrections :)

Comment: @p.dev It's a suspicious choice of type but I cannot "correct" it or other suggest replacements without auditing your code and knowing what it does

Answer (score 2):

With template alias, you might do:

```
template <typename T>
using svs = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>>;
```