# Overwriting existing type with typedef inside a class

Tags: c++

I want to overwrite a type with a typedef. The rationale for doing this is that one of my class has lot of templates and i want to replace all calls to that class with the templatized class (so that within another class `Achild` means `Achild<T>`. However, i get an error.

```
template <typename T>
   class Achild
   {
   public:
     Achild<T>() = default;


   };

  class Foo
{
        typedef Achild<int> Achild;
        public:
                Foo() = default;

};

int main()
{
        auto foo = new Foo();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
new_test.cpp:12:22: error: declaration of ‘typedef class Achild<int> Foo::Achild’ [-fpermissive]
  typedef Achild<int> Achild;
                      ^~~~~~
new_test.cpp:2:10: error: changes meaning of ‘Achild’ from ‘class Achild<int>’ [-fpermissive]
    class Achild
```

How can i get this to work? The example is only for sample and my reasons for doing this is also related to how i have to get this to work with an existing codebase.

Comment: if you're downvoting, please at least add a comment on why you did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aliasing the type with itself (`Achild` already a type since you declared it in your class). You should instead do:

```cpp
using Child = Achild<int>;
```

Note that you also should use the keyword `using` instead of `typedef` since it is the equivalent (and more robust) in `C++`. See [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11).

Comment: Thanks. This was compiling on msvc so it led me to believe it would work on iso