# Why is an alias declaration not a valid init-statement (/simple-declaration)?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

#### Typedef declarations can, whereas alias declarations cannot, be used as initialization statements?

The [grammar for an *init-statement*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/gram.stmt) is, for C++17, as follows:

> init-statement:
>
> - [expression-statement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement)
> - [simple-declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration)
>
> expression-statement:
>
> - expression_opt;
>
> simple-declaration:
>
> - decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list_opt ;
> - attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list ;
> - attribute-specifier-seq_opt decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifier_opt [
>     identifier-list ] initializer ;
>
> [...]

A [*typedef declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.typedef#1) may be used as an *init-statement*, and e.g. the following is valid (C++17) code:

```
if (typedef int Foo; true) { (void)Foo{}; }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement

switch(typedef int Foo; 0) { case 0: (void)Foo{}; }
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement
```

whereas an [*alias-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:alias-declaration) may not be used as an *init-statement*:

```
if (using Foo = int; true) { (void)Foo{}; }
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression

switch(using Foo = int; 0) { case 0: (void)Foo{}; }
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression
```

Afaics a typedef declaration is a valid *simple-declaration* as `typedef` is a [*decl-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec#nt:decl-specifier) which is part of a [*decl-specified-seq*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec#nt:decl-specifier-seq) which in turn, by itself, is a valid [*simple-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration), whereas an *alias-declaration* is an entirely different declaration and not a *simple-declaration*.

Much like the answers in [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11), I was always under the impression that alias declarations have the same semantics as and never falls short of typedef declarations, but as is apparent by the examples above (as of C++17?) it does, in use cases restricted to *simple-declaration*:s, particularly C++17 initialization statements (*init-statement*:s).

#### Question:

- Is it indeed a fact that a typedef declaration is a valid *init-statement*/*simple-declaration* whereas an alias declaration is not? Is this an intended "deviation" as of C++17 w.r.t. the previous (near-?)identical semantics of these two types of declarations?

Comment: I'm not sure we can call the semantics the same previously either. `for(typedef int Foo ; ;)` is valid since C++03, but the alias declaration was never valid in this location either. It's the same thing. Honestly, I think it's just not something anyone was ever bothered about, or thought should be made equivalent.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah that is true (as of C++11, as we only had the typedef declaration in C++03). Maybe it's just as simple as that; a non-important corner case. I've never considered ever using a typedef declaration in a `for(...)` statement, though, whereas using a typedef in an init expression in e.g. `if` statements could arguably (or arguably not? :) ) come in handy in some situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it indeed a fact that a typedef declaration is a valid init-statement/simple-declaration whereas an alias declaration is not

Yes, a typedef declaration is a valid init-statement, whereas an alias declaration is not.

> Is this an intended "deviation" as of C++17 w.r.t. the previous (near-?)identical semantics of these two types of declarations?

As noted in [@StoryTeller's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176495/why-is-an-alias-declaration-not-a-valid-init-statement-simple-declaration#comment109965893_62176495), this was not just the case with the expanded contexts of *init-statement*:s in C++17 (adding them to e.g. if and switch statements), but already present since C++03 and a difference between typedef declarations and alias declarations from the start of the introduction of alias declarations in C++11:

```
// C++11 (C++03) (init. statement in for loop iteration statements).
for(typedef int Foo; Foo{} != 0;) {}
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ init-statement

// C++ 11.
for(using Foo = int; Foo{} != 0;) {}
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: expected expression
```