# Determine type of template parameter in template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

I am trying to implement a generic linked list and linked list iterator in C++. I have a node struct as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T m_data;
    Node<T>* m_next;
};
```

I also have a linked list iterator that is a template so it can generate both regular and `const`  iterators.

```
template <typename NodeType>
class LinkedListIterator
{  
private:
    NodeType* m_node;
public:
    LinkedListIterator(NodeType* n);
    T& operator*() const;
};
```

My question is how do I properly declare the `operator*()` function? My expectation is that something like the following should work

```
LinkedListIterator<const Node<T>> my_iter(some_node_pointer);
*my_iter = new_value; // should not work
```

I understand that returning `T` in the `operator*()` does not make sense since this class does not have access to the typename in the `Node` class.

I found a work around by creating an alias to the type inside the `Node` class like so

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    typedef T type_value;
    // rest of Node class...
};
```

and now I can do the following in my iterator class

```
template <typename NodeType>
class LinkedListIterator
{
public:
    typename NodeType::type_value& operator*() const;
};
```

This seems to work and will return the right value. So my question really should be, is this the best way to implement this? Do I need to have `typedef` to create an alias so that I can use that type? Or is there a way to determine the type inside the `LinkedListIterator` class?

Comment: The `typedef` (or better, `using` in C++11 and later) is one way to handle this, yes.  Another way is to just use `auto`, eg: `auto& operator*() const { return m_node->m_data; }`

Comment: The "alias to the type inside" is what the C++ library itself does all the time. You'll be surprised to learn about the `value_type` member of every C++ container, and where that actually comes from. You guessed it. An alias.

Comment: Though not related, I found `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(arg) or T>().pretty_name();`  is helpful to see what's the type of T and param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `typedef` like this is the canonical way to do it and frequently done in the standard library. In fact, all [*LegacyIterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) should define `value_type`, `difference_type`, `reference`, `pointer`, and `iterator_category`. Only then can their traits be accessed universally using [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

For example:

```cpp
// a simple forward iterator
struct Iterator {
    using value_type = int;
    using reference = value_type &;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    // LegacyIterators also need two operators to be defined:

    // the result of operator* is unspecified, we can choose it freely
    value_type operator*();
    // operator++ needs to return a reference to self
    Iterator& operator++();
};

// we can now access the traits universally, as can various standard library functions
static_assert (std::is_same_v<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, int> );
```

In summary, what you're doing is the right way to go about it, but you should stick to these exact names so that the standard library can access the traits of your iterator. Also I would recommend using `using` instead of `typedef`. Not only does it have `=` as a visual separator but it's universally applicable, e.g. it can be templated unlike `typedef`. See [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196340/5740428)