# typedef return type in header and source files - what is best practice?

Tags: c++, class, scope, typedef, member-functions

I have a class with a member function with a lengthy return type:

```
/* MyClass.hpp */
namespace foo 
{
  class MyClass
  {
  public:
    SomeNameSpace::Lengthy_return_type_name someFunction(params...); 
  };
}
```

I want to make this more readable without making things confusing for the reader, and I don't necessarily want to expose the typedef to the outside world. So in MyClass.hpp I added the following typedef within MyClass:

```
/* MyClass.hpp */
namespace foo 
{
  class MyClass
  {
  private:
    typedef SomeNameSpace::Lengthy_return_type_name myType;
  public:
    myType someFunction(params...); 
  };
}
```

Now, in MyClass.cpp I have a dilemma because myType is not visible to be able to use as a return type. I could use MyClass::myType if I made the typedef public, but I don't like that since I think it is confusing and also exposes myType. I could also add the typedef to the top of MyClass.cpp, but this might take away from the meaning since readers would have to do a little digging to find out what the type is referring to.

Am I overthinking this? What is best practice in this case?

Comment: Technically, you can use a trailing return type: `auto MyClass::someFunction(...) -> myType`.

Comment: "Now, in MyClass.cpp I have a dilemma because myType is not visible to be able to use as a return type" why do you think this would be a problem? The return type of a public method **is** visible to the outside, whether the typedef is private doesnt really matter

Comment: @idclev463035818, curiously, it actually [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/E1Tddx). :) That's strange. There should be some rule, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: Make the alias public. There is no reason to make it private.

For illustration I take your example one step further. Suppose `myType` is not just an alias but a new type:

```
struct foo {
    private:
       struct myType {};
    public:
       myType someFunction();
};
```

Now lets see what this brings: Is `myType` really private? No.

A caller can do

```
 foo f;
 auto x = f.someFunction();
 using myMyType = decltype(x);
```

Tada, the user has an alias for `myType` called `myMyType`. The return type of a public function is not private! Only the name `foo::myType` is private, but types being referd to by different names is common. There is no point in trying to hide that name. The only thing you achieve is to force the user to use a different name.

Also consider that one might expect the definition

```
 foo::myType foo::someFunction() {}
```

to fail to compile, because `foo::myType` is defined in the private section of `foo`. Though, return types of public methods cannot be really private. If the above definition was not allowed you could write:

```
 decltype( declval<foo>().someFunction() ) foo::someFunction() {}
```

So there would be really no point in disallowing the above definition.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zc6Yrs)

Comment: And why does `foo::myType foo::someFunction() {}` compile, but `foo::myType someFunction() {}` fail from the language-lawyer perspective?

Comment: @Evg I have to admit that thats the weak point in my argumentation. I am a very poor language-lawyer. I cannot tell you what exactly makes one compile and the other not. Consider that `foo` could have a private nested class `myType2` that does not leak through the public interface, then `foo::myType2 someFreeFunction()` cannot be right

Comment: @Evg my guess is that the answer is somewhere here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Comment: @Evg coincidentally a somewhat related question just popped up: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64275733/4117728

Comment: @Evg Wouldn't `foo::myType someFunction() {}` be a free-standing function which just happens to use a type defined else where as return type. Since that type is not accessible it errors out. Some standardese prevents that happening if it is a member function instead. That's my reasoning.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, exactly! The question is what that _some standardese_ is.

Comment: @Evg My standardese-foo has been non-existent for the past 12 years. I'll take your word for it. :) Reputation hath its privilege, afterall!

Answer (score 3):

Definitely overthinking, because your callers need to have full definition available anyway. No point in restricting access to something they have to know.

Besides, what's the point in hiding a `typedef` from callers when it is used as a return type? It doesn't buy you anything, there's no encapsulation involved in this particular case.

Lastly, may I recommend switching to modern syntax for doing the same thing?

`using myType = SomeNameSpace::Lengthy_return_type_name;`

You will eventually come to love this, since it offers so much more than plain typedefs, e.g. [alias templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Answer (score 2):

That's a good idea to define all types at the beginning.

Just have a look at any class implementation of the Standard Library: [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) by example. The "Member type section" is filled by useful typedefs.

If you look at the implementation details, the general scheme is:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
{

  typedef _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>         _Base;
  typedef typename _Base::_Tp_alloc_type    _Tp_alloc_type;
  // ...

public:
  typedef _Tp value_type;
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector>  iterator;
  typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, vector> const_iterator;
  // ...

public:
  iterator begin();
  const_iterator begin() const;
  // ...
};
```

If the method is public you should declare the typedef to be public too. Just stay coherent and consistent.

---

As mentioned by others and since C++11, it is better to use `using` instead of `typedef`, see [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10747810/2001017)