# Access checking rules for template argument list in (particularly explicit) specializations

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

Consider the following class template `A` and class `B` which private defines a nested class `C` and enum class `E`:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A {};

class B { 
    class C {};
    enum class E {};
};
```

According to [[temp.explicit]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#12):

> The usual access checking rules do not apply to names used to specify explicit instantiations. [...]

we may refer e.g. to private types such as `B::C` and `B::E` in the template argument list when specifying explicit instantiations:

```
// OK: explicit instantiation definition.
template class A<B::C, B::E>;
```

I'm trying to find the similar segment in the standard that specifies whether the same waiving of access right restrictions  when specifying the template argument list for (partial and particularly explicit/full) specializations.

```
// Partial specialization.
template<typename U>
class A<B::C, U> {};

// Explicit(/full) specialization.
template<>
class A<B::C, B::E> {};
```

The partial specialization fails to compile in Clang

> ```
> error: 'C' is a private member of 'B'
> ```

whereas GCC accepts it. Possibly this is due to different instantiation rules between GCC and Clang. Both GCC and Clang accepts the explicit(/full) specialization.

I'm suspecting the explicit(/full) specialization is well-formed whereas the partial specialization is ill-formed (implicitly due to default rules). However, for the former, I have not been able to find a statement similar to that of [[temp.explicit]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#12) in [[temp.expl.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec).

#### Question

- Where, in the standard, is it specified (implicitly or explicitly) that the usual access checking rules do not apply for the template argument list for (particularly explicit/full) specializations?

Comment: There’s no such thing as a “partial explicit specialization”, just “partial specializations” and “explicit specializations” (sometimes called “full specializations”).

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right, thanks ([\[temp.spec\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#3): _An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by `template<>`_). I've will update the wording of the question accordingly. Do you happen to also know the answer, whether we may or may not legally waive access checking rules for explicit(/full) specializations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule here was changed shortly after C++17 was finished by [P0692](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0692r1.html), replacing what was then [temp.explicit]/14 with what is [temp.class.spec]/10 (for partial specializations) and [temp.spec]/6 (for explicit specializations and instantiations) in C++20.  The paper mentions that it was (largely) standardizing existing practice, so it’s not surprising that some compilers (continue to) allow it even in prior language modes.

---

> #### Access Checking on Specializations
>
> **Abstract**
>
> This paper attempts to address a long-standing hole in the ability for
> developers to specialize templates on their private and protected
> nested class-types. It also identifies an implementation divergence
> between compilers.
>
> **Abstract Code Example**
>
> To be clear about what is being discussed, the following code is a
> minimal example:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> struct trait;
>
> class class_ {
>   class impl;
> };
>
> // Not allowed in standard C++ (impl is private)
> template<>
> struct trait<class_::impl>;
> ```
>
> It is important to note that even though the above specialization of
> trait is not allowed according to the standard, it **builds with all
> compilers that were tested**, including various versions of gcc, clang,
> icc, and msvc. Already, for the sake of standardizing existing
> practice, one might argue that this should be allowed. [...]

Comment: Ah, the paper even covers the implementation divergence between e.g. GCC and Clang for the case of partial specializations. It may be worth noting that the paper mentions that the case of explicit specializations _"... builds with all compilers that were tested, including various versions of gcc, clang, icc, and msvc."_. I plan to make use of this along with hidden friend injections, but only in explicit specializations (with the appropriate protections against ODR-violations). Do you think the latter still falls under the scope of ...

Comment: ...  [WG21/CWG issue 2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118), or is that issue mainly targeting using the technique to provide a hidden friend definition in a non-fully specialized template (such that meta state via the friend will depend in instantiation order)?

Comment: @dfri: I think your analysis is correct: hidden friends are problematic only in cases like using SFINAE to test whether instantiation has occurred.

Comment: Sounds right, thanks for your feedback on that tangent.