# Difference between defining macro and "using" in c++

Tags: c++, macros, long-integer, using

So I was recently looking at competitive programming, and many people have the following code in their program to make it faster to type:

```
#define ll long long
```

For every instance of `ll`, `long long` will be replaced. However, I also saw another similar thing:

```
using ll = long long
```

Is there any difference between using one or the other, and when should I use which?

Comment: The `ll` macro is a token substitution, which is applied at the token level.  If you have `void foo(int ll);` it'll get substituted to `void foo(int long long);`.  Not terribly different than if you had used `sed` to do a search-and-replace.  The `using` version honors scope, and is a type alias rather than a token substitution, and is part of C++ core language rather than the C preprocessor.  In the particular use case cited in the question, I'd recommend using neither.  But I don't do competitive programming.

Comment: `using` is limited in scope, which means you can deliberately constrain it as needed.  A macro works by text substitution, which means its scope is unlimited (after the macro is defined) and that can cause surprises.     More generally, however, using a name like `ll` for `long long` is an extremely bad habit.   The fact it is regularly used on competitive programming sites is evidence that such sites are not useful for learning good technique.

Comment: never use a macro in C++ if you have an alternative.

Comment: The duplicate targets have `typedef` instead of `using`, but these two are similar.  Related: [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10747810/9716597)