# Can I use "using" instead of "typedef" for a pointer to class member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pos {
    int x;
    float y;
};

typedef int Pos::* pointer_to_pos_x;
//using pointer_to_pos_x = ???;

int main()
{
    Pos pos;
    pointer_to_pos_x a = &Pos::x;
    pos.*a = 100;
    cout << pos.x << endl;
}
```

Can I use `using` instead of `typedef` in this situation?

I have searched some information on the web: Some people say `using` can replace `typedef`, but how can I replace this? (Any documentation or blog would also be helpful.)

Comment: `using pointer_to_pos_x = int Pos::*`

Comment: using is the same as typedef but with inverted order of types. I prefer using as it has the "natural" order and syntax as any other assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this:

```cpp
using pointer_to_pos_x = int Pos::*;
```

Virtually all cases of a `typedef XXX aaa;` can be converted readily to `using aaa = XXX;`. You may also find this Q/A useful: [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10747810/10871073)