# C++ using v typedef typename

Tags: c++, declaration, typedef, type-alias

Instead of using `typedef typename` for the iterator is it possible to use `using` keyword?

I tried `using schedulable_ops_t::iterator = schedulable_ops_iterator_t;` but I get an error  `is not a base type for type`.

Answer (score 0):

This record

```
using schedulable_ops_t::iterator = schedulable_ops_iterator_t;
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
using schedulable_ops_iterator_t = typename schedulable_ops_t::iterator;
```

Comment: The "using" directive let's you define types similar to how you would assign values. I.e. `variable = value` is the idea for `new_type_name = type`. That is one of the reasons "using" is now preferred to typedef. It is easier to work with since the order of thinking is no longer "reversed".

Comment: It also allows templating. There’s no reason to still use `typedef`.

Comment: `typedef` used the thinking of variable declarations: `typedef type identifier`, so nothing fundamentally wrong with its thinking direction either. There are more important reasons for `using` (see. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11)