# #define vs typedef vs using for type alias

Tags: c++, alias, typedef, using

In C++, what is the preferred way to define type alias?

```cpp
#define intAliasType int
typedef int intAliasType
using intAliasType = int;
```

I heard that you shouldn't use `#define`, and `typedef` is discouraged in C++, so I should use `using`. But is that true?

Comment: #define is a bad practice in C++ and C. It makes debugging difficult: you see different types in a debugger and a source code. As for `using` or `typedef`, this question is answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11.

Comment: Yes use : using.